# Need some help converting VB.NET code to C#

Tags: c#, code-conversion

I have a CRC class written in VB.NET. I need it in C#. I used an online converter to get me started, but I am getting some errors.

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
iLookup = (crc32Result & 0xff) ^ buffer(i);
```

On that line, the compiler gives me this error:

> **Compiler Error Message:** CS0118: 'buffer' is a 'variable' but is used like a 'method'

Any ideas how I could fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: rep win for anyone who answered this question within the first minute :P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change `buffer(i)` to `buffer[i]`

Comment: Dammit! Beat me by seconds! +1

Comment: More like the Beat Jon Skeet effect.

Comment: @Matthew Jones: yeah, except he gets more rep than you even if he answers the question 10 days after it was posted.  He transcends quickness.

Comment: If you have five answers and Jon Skeet has five answers, Jon Skeet has more rep than you.

Answer (score 10):

Change buffer(i) to buffer[i]  as VB array descriptors are () and C# array descriptors are [].

Answer (score 7):

Use brackets instead of parentheses.

```
iLookup = (crc32Result & 0xff) ^ buffer[i];
```

Answer (score 5):

```
buffer[i];  //not buffer(i)
```

you used parenthesis instead of brackets.

Answer (score 5):

You need square brackets instead of round ones at the end of the second line.

^ buffer[i];

Answer (score 5):

You want to change the () to [].  Array indexing in C# is done using square brackets, not parentheses.

So

```
iLookup = (crc32Result & 0xff) ^ buffer[i];
```

Answer (score 5):

it should be

iLookup = (crc32Result & 0xff) ^ buffer**[**i**]**

Answer (score 0):

I assume there are some lines missing between these two? Otherwise, you are always going to be doing an XOR with zero...

"buffer" is a byte array, and is accessed with the square brackets in C#. "buffer(i);" looks to the C# compiler like a method call, and it knows you have declared it as a variable. Try "buffer[i];" instead.